none of my CSS or JS files, or even my images are connecting to my HTML page. There are errors for all of them in the site console
This is a error
(GET File:///C:/asset/photo/soha.jRg
index.htm1:30
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for index.html:1
resource
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/a11.min.css'
with computed SHA-512 integrity
"DTOQO9RHCH3ppGqchaEA1BIZOC6xoKalwEs₩9c2QQeAIftl+VegovInee1c9QK4TctmlFm13TZy
e+giMm8e2LwA=='. The resource has been blocked.)
its my code. <link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/css/stayl.css" type="/css/stayl.css">
I checked the addresses several times and changed the storage location. I also ensured my internet connection multiple times and reviewed the code for errors, but I still don't understand where the issue is.
